# Duplicate entries on nested attributes with decent-exposure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

**This is a re-edit of a previous post**

I previously thought that this problem was cocoon related but now I don't think so because the following code doesn't even invoke cocoon

Every time I update my form that contains nested attributes the number of nested records doubles. From what I can gather this happens when the form is called because I immediately see an update before I do anything and the form is presented with with duplicate entries

I have the relevant code for my view in HAML below -

```
  %h3 Household Members
    = f.simple_fields_for :neighbors   do  |neighbor|
    = render 'neighbor_fields', :f => neighbor
```

I am using decent-exposure with my controller so the controller looks like this:

```
class HouseholdsController < ApplicationController

  expose(:households)
  expose(:household, strategy: StrongParametersStrategy)

  def create
    if household.save
      redirect_to households_path, notice: 'Household was successfully created.'
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end

def update
  if household.save
    redirect_to households_path, notice: 'Household was successfully updated.'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  household.destroy

redirect_to households_path, notice: 'Household deleted.'
end
```

How can I keep my nested attributes from doubling?

Comment: I am using decent exposure so my controllers are simple - I've tried and the number of nested attributes doubles every time I update

Comment: Which version of decent_exposure ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I've never used decent exposure before, but I have come across the same problem using nested forms, with and without cocoon, the cause was the same in both cases. It has to do with strong parameters, and not white listing the `:id` of the nested attribute.

I'm not sure I exactly get what you're trying to do, so I'll give a classic kind of posts/comments example. If you had a form for posts, and you wanted to dynamically add comment fields, the strong parameters in your controller would look something like this.

```
params.require(:post).permit(:content, comments_attributes: [:id, :content, :_destroy])
```

You need to white list `:id`, `:_destroy`, and whatever other attributes your nested field has. If there's no `:id` associated with the comment, then rails considers that it's a new comment and makes a new record for it. When you white list the `:id`, then rails knows it's an existing object, and then just updates it.